# Remove string 1 time from other string

Tags: vb.net, winforms

my string is for example : `111`

i want to remove `1` from my string

result:

```
11
```

what i have tried:

```
Replace(string, "1", "")
```

result : Null

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `Count` argument to the `Replace()` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.80).aspx

```
Replace("11111", "1", "", , 1)
```

It allows you to limit the number of replacements.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Replace(yourstring, "1", "", , 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace has a Count parameter, which says how many times to do the string replacement.  So what you want is:

```
Replace(string, "1", "", 1, 1)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bt3szac5(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are several ways to do so.

Two of them are:  (Use **RIGHT** method)

```
    Dim s As String = "1111"
    Dim newstring1 As String = Strings.Right(s, s.Length - 1)
```

and: (Use **substring** method)

```
    Dim s As String = "1111"
    Dim newstring2 As String = s.Substring(1)
```

But make sure to check `length of string` to avoid getting `ArgumentException`.